# Sql-Alchemy group by and filter by a list of ids

Tags: mysql, sql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Listing table and a Entry table in a mysql database. 
Each Listing has one or more Entries and I am trying to get the list of all the distinct entries that belong to a list of Listing ids and group them by summing up the score value.

```
id_list = "a list of Listing ids"

entries = db.session.query(Entry.entry, sum(Entry.score)).filter(Entry.listing_id.in_(id_list)).group_by(Entry.entry).all()
```

But I am getting this error when I run the above query in Flask:

```
NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression
```

I have tried google but I have not found anything related to my particular case, any ideas what I am doing wrong

Comment: Your use of `sum` looks suspicious. Have you tried `from sqlalchemy import func` and then `entries = db.session.query(Entry.entry, func.sum(Entry.score))...` ?

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

Comment: If you write it as an answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the problem lies with `sum`.

Try `from sqlalchemy import func` and then
`entries = db.session.query(Entry.entry, func.sum(Entry.score))...`